# Generic method not properly recognizing type

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that has a member defined as:

```
Map<Class<? extends Model>, List<? extends Model>> mockStore;
```

In this class I have a method:

```
protected <T extends Model> void insertMockStore(T obj)
{
    mockStore.get(obj.getClass()).add(obj);
}
```

But this method gives a compilation error:

*The method add(capture#8-of ? extends Model) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (T)*

I don't understand this error because T is defined as extending Model, so why would it say T is not applicable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your member declaration says that the values of `mockStore` will be lists containing an unspecified subclass* of `Model`.

The `insertMockStore` method does similarly but there's nothing guaranteeing that the subclass of `Model` passed to `insertMockStore` will be the same as the lists.

What you should do instead is declare `mockStore` like this:

```
Map<Class<? extends Model>, List<Model>> mockStore;
```

An easy-to-remember rule of thumb here is the "PECS rule": producer extends, consumer super. This means that if your member has a collection with type parameter `Foo`, all producer type methods (ones that insert into your collection) will need `T extends Foo` and all consumer type methods (those that return values from the collection) should have `T super Foo`.

*As always with generics, in "subclass" we include the class itself.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple that I missed. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Your `mockStore` has `List<? extends Model>` values so it doesn't know if you can add a `T` to it.

A simpler solution is to simplify your declaration.

```
private final Map<Class, List> mockStore;

@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
protected void insertMockStore(Model obj) {
    mockStore.get(obj.getClass()).add(obj);
}
```

Comment: But I think the OP needs them generic

Comment: @GingerHead not in the example given.  Usually in these cases where the element types match the key you end up using erasure and enforcing it in the methods instead.